# Is there a way in ActionScript 3.0 to basically make a tab either visible or invisible, depending on a bindable boolean variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tabnavigator

This is admittedly very similar to questions which have been asked before, but it is a little different.  Everything I've seen about how to deal with making a tab either apply or not apply to a TabNavigator is, in my opinion, not good enough.  The problems are that the ways to do this that I've seen in my research have issues with either adding a tab a split second after the user sees it missing, or removing a tab a split second after the user sees it present.  Is there not some way to get around this problem?  Thanks!

EDIT: For clarity, I mean, for other stuff like labels and images, we can basically get around this problem by setting their visibility equal to a bindable variable and not entering the screen they're in until that variable has been set.  The equivalent to this approach is what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a small program to showcase the problem?

Comment: Alright.  Give me a little bit to think about how to go about it.

Comment: Sorry, due to other stuff I'm doing at work, it might take longer than I had hoped to get around to this.  I do plan to do so though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ChangeWatcher` to trigger a function when a bindable variable changes. In that function, add or remove the tab based on the variable's value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
               xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;

            [Bindable]
            public var showTab2:Boolean;

            private var watcher:ChangeWatcher;

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                watcher=ChangeWatcher.watch(this, "showTab2", onValueChange);
            }

            private var _tab2:NavigatorContent;

            public function get tab2():NavigatorContent
            {
                if (!_tab2)
                {
                    _tab2=new NavigatorContent();
                    _tab2.label="tab2";
                }
                return _tab2;
            }

            private function onValueChange(event:Event):void
            {
                if (showTab2 && !tabNav.contains(tab2))
                {
                    tabNav.addElement(_tab2);
                }
                else if (!showTab2 && tabNav.contains(tab2))
                {
                    tabNav.removeChild(tab2);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabNav" width="300" height="300">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="tab 1"/>
    </mx:TabNavigator>

    <s:Button label="Add/remove tab2" click="showTab2 = !showTab2"/>
</s:Application>
```